# initialize CLCircularRegion in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, geofencing, clcircleregion

I am fairly new to programming for iOS and am teaching myself how to use Swift. I need to set up geofencing for an app I am making for a class. My problem is when initializing CLCircularRegion I get an error that says "**Use of undeclared type 'center'**". I followed the documents from Apple's developer site and have no clue what I am doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

var manager = CLLocationManager()

@IBAction func startMonitoring(sender: AnyObject) {
    // 43.039278, -87.932479 mccormick hall location
    var latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 43.039278
    var longitude:CLLocationDegrees = -87.932479
    var center:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
    var radius:CLLocationDistance = CLLocationDistance(10.0)
    var identifier:String = "vicmic"

    var geoRegion:CLCircularRegion = CLCircularRegion(center: center, radius: radius, identifier: identifier)

}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Core Location
    manager.delegate = self
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    manager.startUpdatingLocation()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: I can't believe it @TonyMkenu but adding the spaces fixed everything!! That is all I did. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadly .... the code seems ok

1) try to leave spaces before type annotation, example from `var center:CLLocationCoordinate2D` to this `var center: CLLocationCoordinate2D`   and

2) try to clean your DerivedData, restart Xcode..